# А нужно ли столько памяти на сервере под cache?

Tags: ubuntu, кэширование

Сервер Ubuntu 16.04, i7 и 24GB памяти.

```
# free -mh:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            23G        2.6G        193M         80M         20G         20G
Swap:          976M        488M        488M
```

На сервере множество сайтов и страниц. (очень много).
Как видно выше 2.6 GB памяти использовано, остальное все кешированная информация.

Так как страниц очень много, то возникает вопрос: а нужно ли вообще столько памяти, если вероятность запроса одних и тех же данных довольно низкая. Предполагаю, что кэш постоянно перезаписывается новыми данными и использование информации повторно напрямую из кэш-а довольно низкое и редкое.

Нужно как-то оценить, насколько часто используется кэш по назначению (получение данных по запросу пользователя прямо из кэш, без затрат на обработку данных, выполнения php-скриптов и выборок из БД ...).

Comment: Этот кэш не имеет никакого отношения к обработке данных, выполнению php-скриптов и выборкам из БД. Это внутренний кэш ОС, используемый например для кэширования содержимого файлов с диска, а вышеперечисленные действия будут выполняться в любом случае, если вы явно не настроите кэширование в этих самых php и БД.

Comment: Если вдруг у вашего вебсервера многовато лишней памяти, отдайте её серверу БД, подкрутив его настройки. Тот будет всегда рад, и смысл в этом обычно есть.

Comment: http://www.linuxatemyram.ru/